# HTML drop down menu with results loaded in a table/window

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, frame

I'm very inexperienced with coding in general, obviously.  That being said, I would like to have a dropdown menu that users can select an option from.  Once an option is chosen I would then like results/the page to load below it.  I'm assuming this has to be thrown into a table/frame, but again I'm not entirely sure.  Here is what I have for the drop down menu so far.

```
<select name="usa" id="statepick">
    <option value="/world_maps/">World Maps</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var urlmenu = document.getElementById( 'menu1' );
    urlmenu.onchange = function() {
        window.open( this.options[ this.selectedIndex ].value );
    };
</script>
```

Any help with where to look, or just more information would be great.  Thank you